# Import JSON to dataframe and normalize

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have the following json document which i want to import into a dataframe:

```
{
"agents": [
    {
        "core_build": "17",
        "core_version": "7.1.1",
        "distro": "win-x86-64",
        "groups": [
            {
                "id": 101819,
                "name": "O Laptops"
            }
        ],
        "id": 2198802,
        "ip": "x.x.x.x",
        "last_connect": 1539962159,
        "last_scanned": 1539373347,
        "linked_on": 1534964847,
        "name": "x1x1x1x1",
        "platform": "WINDOWS",
        "plugin_feed_id": "201810182051",
        "status": "on",
        "uuid": "ca8b941a-80cd-4c1c-8044-760e69781eb7"
    },
    {
        "core_build": "17",
        "core_version": "7.1.1",
        "distro": "win-x86-64",
        "groups": [
            {
                "id": 101839,
                "name": "G Personal"
            },
            {
                "id": 102037,
                "name": "W6"
            },
            {
                "id": 102049,
                "name": "MS8"
            }
        ],
        "id": 2097601,
        "ip": "x.x.x.x",
        "last_connect": 1539962304,
        "last_scanned": 1539437865,
        "linked_on": 1529677890,
        "name": "x2xx2x2x2",
        "platform": "WINDOWS",
        "plugin_feed_id": "201810181351",
        "status": "on",
        "uuid": "7e3ef1ff-4f08-445a-b500-e7ce3ca9a2f2"
    },
    {
        "core_build": "14",
        "core_version": "7.1.0",
        "distro": "win-x86-64",
        "id": 2234103,
        "ip": "x6x6x6x6x",
        "last_connect": 1537384290,
        "linked_on": 1537384247,
        "name": "x7x7x7x",
        "platform": "WINDOWS",
        "status": "off",
        "uuid": "0696ee38-402a-4866-b753-2816482dfce6"
    }],
"pagination": {
    "limit": 5000,
    "offset": 0,
    "sort": [
        {
            "name": "name",
            "order": "asc"
        }
    ],
    "total": 14416
 }
}
```

I've written the following code for the same purpose:

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

with open('out.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

df = json_normalize(data, 'agents', [['groups', 'name']], errors='ignore')
print(df)
```

This unpacks all the fields within 'agents'(along with the 'groups' field as a multi-value field) as is, along with a new field called 'groups.name' which is null(all values are NaN).

I only wish to unpack the fields within the 'agents' field into a dataframe, with the fields within 'groups' field being unpacked into individual columns ('core_build', 'core_version', 'distro', 'groups.name', 'id', 'ip','last_connect', 'last_scanned', 'linked_on', 'name', 'platform','plugin_feed_id', 'status', 'uuid').

How can I achieve this?

Edit:
Doing the following

```
df = json_normalize(pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(i) for i in data['agents']]).to_dict('r'))
```

returns an error
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Comment: Where is your `groups` field in your third dictionary?

Comment: It doesn't exist

Comment: This is now a totally different question considering you have missing fields in your structure.....

Comment: Any idea how I could get around this?

Comment: `my_json['agents'][2]['groups'] = []`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.concat()` with a list comprehension:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(i) for i in my_json['agents']])
```

Or try this if you would like to unpack the `group` column of type `dict` to separate columns:

```
df = json_normalize(pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(i) for i in my_json['agents']]).to_dict('r'))
```

Yields:

```
  core_build core_version      distro  groups.id groups.name       id  \
0         17        7.1.1  win-x86-64     101819   O Laptops  2198802   
1         17        7.1.1  win-x86-64     101893   V Laptops  2169839   
2         17        7.1.1  win-x86-64     101839    Personal  2097601   
3         17        7.1.1  win-x86-64     102037          Wi  2097601   
4         17        7.1.1  win-x86-64     102049         MS8  2097601   

        ip  last_connect  last_scanned   linked_on      name platform  \
0  x.x.x.x    1539962159    1539373347  1534964847  x1x1x1x1  WINDOWS   
1  x.x.x.x    1539962767    1539374603  1533666075  x2x2x2x2  WINDOWS   
2  x.x.x.x    1539962304    1539437865  1529677890  x3x3x3x3  WINDOWS   
3  x.x.x.x    1539962304    1539437865  1529677890  x3x3x3x3  WINDOWS   
4  x.x.x.x    1539962304    1539437865  1529677890  x3x3x3x3  WINDOWS   

  plugin_feed_id status                                  uuid  
0   201810182051     on  ca8b941a-80cd-4c1c-8044-760e69781eb7  
1   201810171657     on  9400817b-235b-423b-b163-c4c86f973232  
2   201810181351     on  7e3ef1ff-4f08-445a-b500-e7ce3ca9a2f2  
3   201810181351     on  7e3ef1ff-4f08-445a-b500-e7ce3ca9a2f2  
4   201810181351     on  7e3ef1ff-4f08-445a-b500-e7ce3ca9a2f2
```

Comment: pd.DataFrame accepts dicts. Never really understood what from_dict() is good for. :)

Comment: This is not equal to `pd.DataFrame(my_json['agents'])`, as it breaks out the individual `dicts` in the `groups` column into separate rows

Comment: @rahlf23 you are right. But my first comment stands.

Comment: True, I suppose I'll edit my answer to reflect that. Seems like `from_dict()` is useful in the case when you are trying to construct from an input similar to "Of the form `{field : array-like}` or `{field : dict}`"

Comment: Doing this returns an error "If using all scalar values, you must pass an index". How do I fix it?

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue, can you update your post with **exactly** what you've used as an input and the associated code?